# Simple PHP error T_print error

Tags: php

```
include 'connect.php';
msql_select_db("u972015033_jobss"); or die("Could not find DB");
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $query = msql_query("SELECT * FROM job_search WHERE job_name LIKE '%$searchq%'"); or die("Could not find");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0){
        $output = 'There was no results found';
        else{
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $jobname = $row['job_name'];
                $jobdesc = $row['job_desc'];
                $jobcomp = $row['job_company'];
                $output .= '<div> '.$jobname.' '.$jobdesc.' '.$jobcomp.'</div>';
                echo = "$output";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I dont know what is the problem please help
Its a basic script to query a database and display 
the output

Comment: you're not giving the link identifier in mysql_select_db()

Comment: Your missing close } for if before else.

Comment: There's multiple syntax errors in your code, please do some basic debugging first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of error:

1. msql_select_db("u972015033_jobss"); or die("Could not find DB");  // it should be mysql_select_db("u972015033_jobss") or die("Could not find DB");
2. $query = msql_query("SELECT * FROM job_search WHERE job_name LIKE '%$searchq%'"); or die("Could not find");  //must be: $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job_search WHERE job_name LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("Could not find");
3. before else close '}'
4. echo = "$output"; //remove the "="

Comment: that's basically what I said also, but with a small difference: I don't think he's missing the closing curly brace, he placed it in the wrong place, after the entire block

Comment: @mishu, Yes you are right. I did not notice your comment